# Classifier for binary images

Tags: computer-vision

I have some binary images like:
[image: Binary image]

And I have a training set of images from the objects (RGB) I want to detect in the binary image (not only classify). As you can see these images contain some error, noise and several other objects.

I am a little bit lost of what technique to use or what to do?

I have used in the past other methods like deep neural networks and cascade classifiers, but I want to explore alternatives.

Comment: From that image it looks pretty difficult to detect and classify anything. More info on what you're trying to do might help -- basically it would be good to know all the signal that are available to do the detection (e.g. is it video? Do you control the binarization?). But if you want a generic answer, Haar cascade classifiers are the fastest and probably best for this sort of thing, if you can get/create sufficient training data. SIFT or SURF can also be used to build a detector, by comparing keypoints on the known object image to keypoints in the binary image.

Comment: Is video in one outdoor environment, now I am making background subtraction in one static camera using Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM).